# Regex function that finds patterns of all lengths?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, regex-greedy

How can I make a regex expression that matches single characters as a group as well as repeated sequences?

Here is one that I found (not made by myself): https://regex101.com/r/Vdhjld/1

The regex expression is

```
((?P<X>\S.*?)(?:, (?P=X))+)
```

The string is

```
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 5, 1
```

I want it to be able to get a `Group 'X'` of the single one at the end of the string. Now it just returns `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3` and `2, 5, 2, 5` as a full match, but I want it to return the `1` as well as a full match. How can I do this?

Comment: How about something like `((?P<X>\S.*?)(?:, (?P=X))+)|(\d+(?=,|]))`?

Comment: for numbers? use ([0-9]+)(, [0-9]+)* first group is the must-have first element. the second group matches 0 or more of (comma, space, number)

Comment: Do you mean like this? `((?P<X>\S.*?)(?:, (?P=X))+|[^\s,[\]])`  https://regex101.com/r/jf198X/1

Comment: I think you can only accomplish that using an alternation as others have written. Since regex wants to match as much as possible, even using possessive or control verbs won't give you the results you seek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to either match your original pattern or use a negated character class `[^\s[\]]` to match any char except a whitespace char, `[`, `]` or a comma

```
((?P<X>\S.*?)(?:, (?P=X))+|[^\s,[\]])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jf198X/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, worked perfect. However I wonder if there is a way to do this so that it reads `36, 21, 1` as three items/values, so 36 is one value and 21 is one, and so on. So that `Group 1 = 36`.

Comment: @DenFulaAnkungen You could repeat the character class 1 or more times https://regex101.com/r/1R1ECV/1